# ClassNotFound error when running storm.starter.ExclamationTopology in remote mode

Tags: apache-storm

I was trying to run storm start example in remote mode. 
When I submitted the topology to the storm using:

```
storm jar .\target\storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology myTopology
```

I met following errors from worker logs:
Anybody ever met this kind of problem?
Thanks in advance!

```
2013-06-08 13:32:44 worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: storm.starter.ExclamationTopology$ExclamationBolt
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:70)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:199)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.task$get_task_object.invoke(task.clj:56)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data$fn__3766.invoke(task.clj:158)
    at backtype.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:731)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data.invoke(task.clj:152)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task.invoke(task.clj:163)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor$fn__3922.invoke(executor.clj:267)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__4087.invoke(core.clj:2432)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:473)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
    at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invoke(protocols.clj:30)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5875.invoke(protocols.clj:54)
    at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5828$G__5823__5841.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6030)
    at clojure.core$into.invoke(core.clj:6077)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor.invoke(executor.clj:267)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4348$exec_fn__1228__auto____4349$iter__4354__4358$fn__4359.invoke(worker.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:473)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
    at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:2725)
    at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:2741)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4348$exec_fn__1228__auto____4349.invoke(worker.clj:354)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__4348$mk_worker__4404.doInvoke(worker.clj:323)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:433)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: storm.starter.ExclamationTopology$ExclamationBolt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:64)
    ... 35 more
2013-06-08 13:32:44 util [INFO] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
```

Comment: Did you have look at this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/storm-user/_sfAypsM7E0/BjrDASri_psJ

Comment: Yes, I have read that link before I posted this question here.  Unfortunately, that link discusses problem met when running example in local mode. Quite different from problem i am posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have found solution. The ClassNotFoundException was because the storm couldn't find the submitted jar which was caused  by that the path delimiter on windows is ; while the in storm clojure source code that delimiter is the unix delimiter : .